# how to retrieve id as hidden value in form so that the value get stored as foreign key in the database in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i am unable to extend admin inteface
i tried to extend but it didnt'worked

in settings.py 
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Sfolder"),

so in root folder
there is sfolder inside there 
admin/base_site.html
inside base_site.html

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
```

it didn't override the base.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over complicating your implementation. Instead of passing the `user.id`, you can directly access the value in view like this:

```
<form  method="post" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-agile btn-block w-100">Make An Appointment</button>
</form>
```

And save the value of user in view:

```
# view
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def appointment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AppointmentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            appointment = form.save(commit=False)
            appointment.user = request.user  # get user value here
            appointment.save()
            messages.success(request, f' Succesfully made an appointment!')
            return HttpResponse("success")

    else:
        form = AppointmentForm()
        context = {'form': form, }
        return render(request, 'home_temp/appointment.html', context)
# url
path('appointment/',views.appointment,name='appointment'),
```